# How can you store values using pointer and how can you show all of the values that is stored?

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

So I have this program to store all the data that the user will input.I am using a pointer and I am a bit confused on how to store them all and on how to display all of them.
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num1, num2, result, range;
    int *ptr1 = &num1, *ptr2 = &num2;
    char operation, answer;
    char *ptrop = &operation;
    while(true){
    cout<<"ENTER TWO NUMBERS: \n";
    cin>>*ptr1>>*ptr2;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"CHOOSE OPERATION: ";
    cin>>operation;
    switch(operation){
        case '+':
            result = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
            cout<<"Asnwer is "<<result<<endl;
            break;
        case '-':
                result = *ptr1 - *ptr2;
                cout<<"Asnwer is "<<result<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"NONE\n\n";
    }
    cout<<"\nWANT TO TRY AGAIN? ";
    cin>>answer;
    switch(answer){
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            ptr1++;
            ptr2++;
            range ++;
            system("cls");
            continue;
        default:
            cout<<"VIEW HISTORY?";
            cin>>answer;
                switch(answer){
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'y':
                        for(int i=0;i<=range;i++){
                            cout<<"ADDRESS OF "<<*ptr1<<" is "<<ptr1<<endl;
                            cout<<"ADDRESS OF "<<*ptr2<<" is "<<ptr2<<endl<<endl;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
    }
    }
}
```

I am trying to store all the data but when I view history, it show the same numbers. I am confused, I dont know how to fix this

Comment: Your history has to show a list of values, therefore, you need to define `num1` and `num2` as arrays `int[]`instead of simple `int`s. After, when you do `ptr1++` and `ptr2++`, they will increase the index of the array where they are pointing to. And when you show the history, you need to reset the pointers to the beginning of the arrays.

Comment: @fern17 I am a bit confused. So should it be int num1[ ], like that?

Comment: Look up a tutorial for `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should revise a little the logic, but the idea is: you define dynamic arrays that will store your values. For each operation, you store the values in a position of this array and then you increment the pointer. To see the history, you start from the first position and iterate through till the end.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int result;
    int range = 0; 
    int max_range = 10; // maximum number of operations to do, you could ask this to the user...
    int* num1 = new int[max_range]; // arrays instead of simple ints
    int* num2 = new int[max_range];
    int *ptr1 = &num1[0]; // initialize the pointers to the first position
    int *ptr2 = &num2[0];

    char operation, answer;
    char *ptrop = &operation;
    while(true){
        cout<<"ENTER TWO NUMBERS: \n";
        cin>>*ptr1>>*ptr2;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"CHOOSE OPERATION: ";
        cin>>operation;
        switch(operation){
        case '+':
            result = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
            cout<<"Asnwer is "<<result<<endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = *ptr1 - *ptr2;
            cout<<"Asnwer is "<<result<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"NONE\n\n";
        }
        cout<<"\nWANT TO TRY AGAIN? ";
        cin>>answer;
        switch(answer){
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            ptr1++; // the pointers are updated to the next position
            ptr2++;
            range ++; // increase the number of operations done.
            system("cls");
            continue;
        default:
            cout<<"VIEW HISTORY?";
            cin>>answer;
            switch(answer){
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                ptr1 = &num1[0]; // reset the pointers to the beginning of the arrays
                ptr2 = &num2[0];
                for(int i=0;i<=range;i++){
                    cout<<"ADDRESS OF "<<*ptr1<<" is "<<ptr1<<endl;
                    cout<<"ADDRESS OF "<<*ptr2<<" is "<<ptr2<<endl<<endl;
                    ptr1++; // VERY IMPORTANT!! This moves the pointer to the next value.
                    ptr2++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    delete [] num1; // always delete dynamic arrays.
    delete [] num2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @newbie you want to have an history of operations. An history is a list. A list cannot be stored in a simple `int`. You need an array.

Comment: can i ask what is the new int for because I am a bit confused with that

Comment: i did not used array because I thought that  when the memory address of a variable is incremented, it would act like an array, i think it turned out wrong.

Comment: If you try to access to memory that was not dedicated to your process, you will only see trash.

Comment: can I ask you why did you have delete dynamic arrays?

Comment: Please read the link I sent you above. It is to avoid memory leaks (memory that was allocated and used, but it is no longer used and no one can use it)